# How is memory managed in Python

Tags: python, memory-management, garbage-collection

Is garbage collection done in Python by itself or do we need to do it ourselves.
I used to believe that Python used to manage all sort of memory issues itself and we need worry about memory management.

The reason I am asking this is because I saw gc module in Python documentation
http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html

If memory management is handle by itself then whats the point of this module.

Comment: Did you actually *read* the linked documentation?

Comment: gc is only used to disable or change the functioning of the default garbage collector.Garbage collector is always ON unless you change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the link provided in the question:

> Since the collector ***supplements*** the reference counting already used in Python, you can  disable the collector if you are sure your program does not create reference cycles.

It seems clear enough.

Comment: Ok, I think I should ask for an apology to ask a stupid question. I should have done research. Its just I was in the midway of my project and I read it on some forum that python garbage collection needs to be handled gaving that hyperlink. Anyways, my fault and I am sorry to ask this question.